# jQuery Upload to Public S3 Bucket gives ------WebKitFormBoundary

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3

I have a web page that gets the public S3 bucket name and a unique filename to use for the upload. I'm doing the upload right from javascript using jQuery. The file uploads, but the multipart information is prepended to the file which corrupts it.

I have tried different jQuery ajax parameters like making the contentType 'image/jpeg' and trying to use PUSH instead of PUT. I even tried manually adding the files to the new FormData() object manually as you can see below.

I don't understand how I can write a simple CURL command, which works with no problems, but I can't get an HTML form submitted using jQuery to work. I feel like with jQuery it's being chucked and not put together properly on the S3 bucket side.

**HTML**

```
<form id="upload-image-form" className="clearfix" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="product-images-add-btn" name="product-images-add-btn" type="file" onChange={this.startImageUpload} />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#upload-image-form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    //var formData = new FormData($("#product-images-add-btn")[0]);  
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", $("#product-images-add-btn")[0].files[0]);          

    $.ajax({
        url:         formURL,
        type:        "PUT",
        data:        formData,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:     function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log('Successful image upload!');
            //tempThis.finishImageS3Upload();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.error("Image upload error.");
        }
    });
    return false;
});



startImageUpload: function(){
    var input = $("#product-images-add-btn");
    var files = input[0].files;
    var fileTypes = [".gif",".jpg", ".png"];

    console.log("--- DEBUG. Number of files: "+files.length);

    var tempThis = this;

    if(files.length > 0)
    {
        var ext = input.val().match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[0];

        if(fileTypes.indexOf(ext) > -1)
        {
            var file = files[0];
            var assetData = {
                "filename":    file.name,
                "filesize":    file.size,
                "type":        "IMAGE",
                "format":      file.type
            };


            $.ajax({
                url: "/getImageUploadS3Info",
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: assetData,
                success: function(s3Info){
                    s3Info.filename = file.name;
                    tempThis.uploadImageS3(s3Info);
                },
                error: function(a, x, e){
                    console.error("getS3InfoForUpload() ajax error.");
                }
            });

        }
        else
            console.warn("--- DEBUG. File extension "+ext+" not allowed.");
    }
    else
        console.log("--- DEBUG. No files to upload.");
}


uploadImageS3: function(s3Info){
    if(s3Info.hasOwnProperty("assetId"))
    {        
        $("#upload-image-form").attr('action', s3Info.httpUrl)
            .data('assetId', s3Info.assetId);

        console.log("--- DEBUG: submitting form.");
        $("#upload-image-form").submit();
    }
    else
        console.warn("--- ERROR: the response for getImageUploadS3Info wasn't correct.");

}
```

**S3 files**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryluTBbSMgcV0BEJcC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="NewGrass.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<image byte info stuff>
```

[image]

Comment: I am facing this exact same issue, were you able to fix it?

Comment: No. We ended up going back to sending the file to our back-end Java and having that upload it to S3

Comment: 6 years later and uploading files through jquery/ajax is still a giant pain.

Answer (score 0):

After testing in Firefox (newest), Chrome (newest) and IE10, IE11 and Edge, this solution does work like a charm! No need for overhead of jquery's ajax method here. Browsers (namely IE) did pick up the XMLHttpRequest object. This will get the job done for S3, but I am still working on a solution with jQuery's $.ajax() method to conquer 100% cross-browser-compatibility (but we don't support IE9, so not required on our end):

```
function sendToServer (imgFile) {
    var dateTime = new Date().getTime(),//used for file name
        url = '//bucketUrl?fileName=image' + dateTime + '.png',
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fd = new FormData(),
        fileBlob = dataURItoBlob(img);

    fd.append('file', fileBlob);

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // Every thing ok, file uploaded
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
        }
    };

    xhr.send(fd);
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString,
        byteStringLength,
        mimeString,
        ia,
        i = 0;

    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }
    else {
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }

    byteStringLength = byteString.length

    // separate out the mime component
    mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    ia = new Uint8Array(byteStringLength);

    for(; i < byteStringLength; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {
        type: mimeString
    });
}
```

It looks like you forgot to encode into a blob before sending. That may be all you need. Grab that decodeURItoBlob function and see if that logic works with your jquery ajax method... otherwise, you can use javascript xhr to send it.